# how to fetch data in Laravel with postman

Tags: php, laravel

hello i'm New in Laravel and i'm working on a school project right now i'm building some web service for android i have a university model and a club model that belongs to the university i need to create a get method that lists all the clubs per university any help please

Comment: What does your project setup look like? Are you using laravel valet, using php artisan serve or using some other method?

You would simply have to create a GET request inside of Postman that targets your route. Ex: GET <IP>/my/endpoint

Comment: Have you tried anything? We're not here to write code for you, nor provide code for school assignments. Please try this yourself, and if you have a specific error/issue, post that.

Comment: If you are starting with Laravel and web services, here is a [goog tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/laravel/restful-laravel-api-tutorial) to learn how to build and test a RESTful API with Laravel

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just checked your response to the other answer.

When querying through eloquent, you need to end your statements with `->get();`